# How do get last downloaded image to insert into object placeholder of current keynote slide?

Tags: applescript

Images are key to my work.

I am trying to find a quick way to automate image insertion to keynote. The script I am drafting is to get the last created/downloaded image, and insert it into the current slide on Keynote as a replacement of the master's object placeholder.

### Error from applescript:

"Keynote got an error: Can’t set file name of slide 2 of document id \"B1054797-9A07-4642-AE79-166D1DE72674\" to alias." number -10006 from file name of slide 2 of document id "B1054797-9A07-4642-AE79-166D1DE72674" to alias

```
set myFolder to "/Users/Mingyu/Desktop/UpperEchelon"

tell application "Finder" to set latestFile to item 1 of (sort files of (POSIX file myFolder as alias) by creation date) as alias
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    tell the front document
        tell the current slide
            set thisPlaceholderImageItem to item 1
            set file name of thisPlaceholderImageItem to ¬
                alias
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I expect the script will insert last download image in the folder "UpperEchelon" to a current open slide in Keynote

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You have to set `thisPlaceholderImageItem` to `image 1` rather than to `item 1`
2. You have to set the `file name` to `latestFile` rather than just to `alias`. That's what the error is telling you.

And if the folder is a subfolder of the desktop there is a much shorter syntax

```
set myFolder to "UpperEchelon"

tell application "Finder" to set latestFile to item 1 of (sort files of folder myFolder by creation date) as alias
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    tell the front document
        tell the current slide
            set thisPlaceholderImageItem to image 1
            set file name of thisPlaceholderImageItem to latestFile
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I tried to run it. The error went by "Keynote got an error: Can’t get image 1 of current slide of document 1. Invalid index." number -1719 from image 1 of current slide of document 1.

Comment: If you want to insert the image *as a replacement* I assumed that there is was already an image. If not you have to **create** a new image. Please have a look at https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/index.html. There are a lot of samples how to script Keynote for example [Importing an image vs. Replacing an image](https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/image-placeholder.html)

Comment: Yes, the placeholder replacement was not too necessary. Switched to create new image with the linked URL. Thank you!